# find_all on span tag in Beautiful Soup yields AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Warning: this is only my second attempt at Python code so I may be making errors that will cause distress to a professional:

I'd like to get a list of cities using 'addressLocality' from the set of results in soup_r:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.tjhughes.co.uk/map'
page = requests.get(URL, verify=False)
soup_r = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

this is the type of result I'd like with just the name of the city (in this case = Bradford)

```
single_span = soup_r.find('span',itemprop = 'addressLocality').get_text()
```

I'd like to be able to return the full list of results in the same format as single_span (ie by isoloating the city name) but the following code gives me the error "AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'"

```
spans_fail = soup_r.find_all('span',itemprop = 'addressLocality').get_text()
```

The nearest I can get is by dropping the get_text():

```
spans = soup_r.find_all('span',itemprop = 'addressLocality')
```

...thus returning the results in one bundle:

```
[<span itemprop="addressLocality">Bradford</span>, <span itemprop="addressLocality">Birkenhead</span>, <span itemprop="addressLocality">Bootle</span>, <span itemprop="addressLocality">Bury</span>,
...
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Sheffield</span>, <span itemprop="addressLocality">St Helens</span>, <span itemprop="addressLocality">Widnes</span>]
```

Assuming this is the best I can do, I still get tied in knots when I try to re-arrange the results.

For instance this just returns Bradford 52 times which baffles me because there are only 26 cities in the original list so I don't know how I'm doubling up, let alone how to access the other 25:

```
cities = []
for check in soup:
    check = soup.find('span',itemprop = 'addressLocality').text
    cities.append(check)
```

I was looking for an elegantly simple solution, and I appreciate that I might need a workaround, but I can't see how else to approach this and so any input is appreciated.

Comment: Always share the entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to obtain your list of cities.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.tjhughes.co.uk/map'
page = requests.get(URL, verify=False)
soup_r = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

cities = [span.get_text() for span in soup_r.select('span[itemprop="addressLocality"]')]
print(cities)
```

Prints:

```
['Bradford', 'Birkenhead', 'Bootle', 'Bury', 'Chelmsford', 'Chesterfield', 'Glasgow', 'Cumbernauld', 'London', 'Coventry', 'Dundee', 'Durham', 'East Kilbride', 'Glasgow', 'Harlow', 'Hartlepool', 'Liverpool', 'Maidstone', 'Middlesbrough', 'Newcastle upon Tyne', 'Nuneaton', 'Oldham', 'Preston', 'Sheffield', 'St Helens', 'Widnes']
```

Comment: As hoped, that's an elegantly simple solution.  I'm starting to fall for this language, and it's made an awful lot easier by helpful and prompt responses like this.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When you get down to a list of single elements sometimes you have to do string chopping.

```
spans = soup_r.find_all('span',itemprop = 'addressLocality')

# [<span itemprop="addressLocality">Bradford</span>, <span 

cities = []
for span in spans:
    left_angle=span.find('>'+1)
    sec_rangle=spane.find('<',1)
    city=span[left_angle:sec_rangle]
    print(city)
    cities.append(city)
print(cities)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'm not quite sure what you're demonstrating.  I've tried correcting what I think are some typos but I still end up with errors so I must be missing something.  I'll try to give more constructive feedback when I have more time to explore.